# Learn python the hard way excercise 50

Tags: python, setuptools

So, I´m a newbie of python, but had no real problems with the book until this one..
At this point we´re going to install `lpthw.web`, but when trying installing it I get an error.

This is what we´re told to write into terminal:

```
$ sudo pip install lpthw.web
```

**And this is the error i keep getting:**

> Exception: Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/pip-1.2.1-py2.6.egg/pip/basecommand.py",
>   line 107, in main
>       status = self.run(options, args)   File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/pip-1.2.1-py2.6.egg/pip/commands/install.py",
>   line 248, in run
>       import setuptools ImportError: No module named setuptools
>
> Storing complete log in /Users/user/Library/Logs/pip.log
>   Users-MacBook-Pro:~ user$

**And yes, I went to my pip folder and saw that I have nothing with setuptools there. How and why did this happen?**

**I´m baffled, any advices?**

Comment: You could try installing [`setuptools`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools).  the install is quite painless.  It's as easy as downloading the `.egg` for you python version and then running in a shell:  `<sudo> sh setuptools-0.6c11-py2.6.egg`

Comment: Yout question is related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9305316/python-import-web-not-working

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu you can get setuptools via apt-get:

```
$ sudo apt-cache search setuptools
[sudo] password for me: 
...
python-setuptools - Python Distutils Enhancements (setuptools compatibility)
...
python3-setuptools - Python3 Distutils Enhancements (setuptools compatibility)
```