# NameError: name 'base' is not defined in wsgisession example application

Tags: python, wsgi

I am trying to start a test server with the example application from this web page:

http://pythonweb.org/projects/webmodules/doc/0.5.3/html_multipage/lib/example-wsgiSession.html

However, when I try to launch my WSGI server, I get the following error message:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "wsgiSession.py", line 3, in 
    class simpleApp(base.BaseApplication):
NameError: name 'base' is not defined

I downloaded the plain text version of the script from here:

http://pythonweb.org/projects/webmodules/doc/0.5.3/html_multipage/lib/wsgiSession.txt

I did not make *any* changes to this code. I simply put it in my project home directory and specified it in the command line parameters of my WSGI server, as I would with any other python script. All other python scripts in my project directory work fine, it is just this one script that is giving me this error.

How can I make it work?

Comment: The very first line of that script is: `from web.wsgi import *` presumably, base is defined in that module somewhere.  Do you have that module installed?

Comment: When I first tried running this application, I got an error saying "ImportError: No module named web". At first, I tried doing "pip install web", but that didn't work. Pip couldn't find anything named "web." Eventually I stumbled across this StackOverflow post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9305316/python-import-web-not-working Whoop's post stated that you should use "aptitude install python-webpy" so I did that and that solved the import error. I presume this did install the module.

Comment: Please let me know if "aptitude install python-webpy" is not the correct way to install the module. Apparently the module is not properly installed if I am getting this NameError

Comment: You are looking at the documentation for [pythonweb](http://pythonweb.org/), which is different from webpy

Comment: How I install pythonweb? I tried doing "aptitude install python-pythonweb" but it said the package couldn't be found.

Comment: You can download it from the home page. However note the scary warning: *29th June 2006 - Work on pythonweb has officially stopped so the code is no longer maintained* -- are you sure you want to use pythonweb?